# Lucene, negative boost on field mismatch

Tags: lucene

I'm considering if Lucene is a good tool for a task.

I have data containing company names, unique identifying numbers (i.e. TAX_ID, statistical reporting ID number etc.).

Is it possible to create an index and queries it in a way that allows to "down boost" records with mismatched this unique identifier fields.

- scores goes up if TAX_ID matches between document and query,
- it stays neutral if there is no TAX_ID either in document or query,
- but score goes down if TAX_ID differs between document and query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do that, is to index a particular flag value in TAX_ID when the document does not have a tax id, and then use boosts to provide the scoring you want.  So, your queries would look something:

```
TAX_ID:1234 TAX_ID:NOTAXID^0.5
```